# Are bounded linear maps continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B(X, Y)$ be the set of bounded linear maps from $X$ to $Y$ (i.e. such that $\sup_{||x|| \leq 1} L(x) < \infty$).  Is $L \in B(X, Y)$ continuous?  What about if $X$ is a Banach space?  What about if $Y$ is a Banach space?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess $X$ and $Y$ are normed space (a norm is missing after the $\sup$). Did you try to prove it,

Comment: Also consider the neat fact that in finite dimensional normed spaces all linear maps are bounded.

Comment: Well I stared at the statement a bit but it seems kind of counterintuitive.  You think I should try to prove it for realsies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem 5.4 from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*: For a linear transformation $\Lambda$ of a normed linear space $X$ into a normed linear space $Y$, the following are equivalent:

- $\Lambda$ is bounded.
- $\Lambda$ is continuous.
- $\Lambda$ is continuous at one point of $X$.

The proof is very straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that that's a theorem.  I saw it in my notes but thought it might be wrong because continuity seems like a very strong condition.  I thought continuity was $\exists c$ such that $||L(x)|| < c||x||$, and boundedness was $||L(x)|| < c$, so for small values of $||x||$ shouldn't continuity be stronger?

Comment: No, continuity is for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\|x_2-x_1\|_X<\delta$ implies that $\|Lx_2-Lx_1\|_Y<\epsilon$. Linearity is the glue which makes all of these things equivalent.

Comment: Well I guess when you put it that way, $||Lx_2 - Lx_1|| < ||L|| ||x_2 - x_1|| \to 0$ for bounded $L$.  Thanks!  I think I was just staring at the wrong condition.