# Proof that a linear transformation is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

I got started recently on proofs about continuity and so on. So to start working with this on $n$-spaces I've selected to prove that every linear function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous at every $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since I'm just getting started with this kind of proof I just want to know if my proof is okay or if there's any inconsistency. My proof is as follows:

Since $f$ is linear, we know that there's some $k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|\leq k|x|$ for every $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, in that case let $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\varepsilon >0$. Consider $\delta = \varepsilon /k$ and suppose $|x-a|<\delta$, in that case we have:

$$|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(x-a)|\leq k |x-a|<k \frac{\varepsilon}{k}=\varepsilon$$

And since $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$ we have that $f$ is continuous at $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Since $a$ was arbitrary, $f$ is continous in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is this proof fine? Or there was something I've missed on the way?

Comment: The proof looks OK. The crucial step is showing the existence of $k$. Is this a theorem that you've already proved?

Comment: Sure, I've proved that result before, it's one of the exercises of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, and since it seemed pretty important I proved it before anything else.

Comment: Then you're done. The proof looks good.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @AymanHourieh!

Comment: How did you proof the existence of $k$ without using the fact that linear transformations are continuous?

Comment: @JKEG While applying Extreme Value Theorem is circular, Spivak proves it without using compactness by adding the lengths of the column vectors and multiplying by length.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This proof is correct modulo result you stated in the begining, i.e. 
$$
\text{there exist $k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)|\leq k|x|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$}
$$
Proof of this fact is much more interesting and uses compactness of unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Not necessarily. You can get this easily by applying Cauchy-Schwarz row by row.

Comment: @TedShifrin for any norm?

Comment: Haha. It seems pretty clear the OP is using the Euclidean norm here.

Comment: Could you show me how to do ir whit the unit ball?

Comment: @VictorFranciscoSalazarGarci see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289306/linear-function-between-finite-dimensional-vectorspaces-is-continuous)

Comment: Is it fine to write the following? Consider $\varepsilon \gt \|f(x_0)-f(x)\|=\|f(x_0-x)\|=\|f(\alpha)\|=\|r\| \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $r \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_0 \neq x$. Since $\|x_0-x\| \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\exists k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\|r\| = k\|x_0-x\|$. Thus, $k\|x_0-x\| \lt \varepsilon$. Hence, let $\|x_0-x\| \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{k}$.