# If $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear and injective, then $T^{-1}(B)$ is Borel for Borel $B$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> If $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is linear and injective, then $T^{-1}(B)$ is Borel for Borel $B$.

Is it possible to prove this theorem?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous

Comment: Yes, it is possible to prove this theorem.