# Uniqueness of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

The [wikipedia entry for bounded operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator#Linearity_and_boundedness) shows that for the space $X$ of trigonometric polynomials on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with norm
$$\lVert P\rVert = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\lvert P(x)\rvert \operatorname{d}\!x,$$
the operator $L: X\rightarrow X$ by $P\mapsto P^{\prime}$ is not a bounded operator.

It is not clear to me why there couldn't be something like a bounded linear operator $K$ on a larger space $X\subseteq Y$ such that the restriction of $K$ onto $X$ agrees with $L$. Is there an obvious uniqueness theorem I am missing?

I suspect that this can be proven by contradiction using the Riesz representation theorem, but I think this might be overkill and I am missing a comparatively trivial argument.

Comment: I dont get your question. If the restriction of $K$ agrees with $L$, then $K$ can not be bounded as $L$ is not bounded.

Comment: That is basically my question. I don't understand why that is the case and if it should be obvious or not.

Comment: $(e^{i n x})' = in e^{inx}$ so $||(e^{i n x})'|| = n ||e^{i n x}||$ i.e. your operator is not bounded (for the $||.||_1$ norm) if on the $(e^{inx})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ it is the derivative operator

Comment: If the operator $K$ identifies with the differential operator, and $K$ is bounded then the differential operator must also be bounded. Yes, it should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boundedness depends of the norm. $X\subseteq Y$ must be interpreted not only as set-theoretical inclusion, but that $X$ inherits the norm of $Y$.

Comment: and  for any norm, the derivative operator on the $e^{inx}$ on $[-\pi;\pi]$ is unbounded

Comment: I think that is the big idea I was missing, but I will think about it for a little while before I accept an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @user1952009, take a finite-dimensional subspace...

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla : a linear operator on a subspace of $[-\pi;\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ which is the derivative on the whole family $(e^{inx})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ cannot be bounded, whatever the norm considered

Comment: @user1952009, in a *finite* dimensional subspace **any** linear operator is bounded. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous. The span of all the $x\mapsto e^{inx}$ is *infinite* dimensional.

Comment: @user1952009, sorry I've misunderstand you.

Comment: I think that's interesting, it justifies why on wikipedia we can read that the problem is that the derivative operator is unbounded no matter the norm considered. what saves us is that it is closed, so it keeps some of the properties of finite dimensional operators (it preserves the convergence of sequences for most (all?) norms)