# Closed Graph Theorem on Finite Dimensional Banach Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, linear-transformations

My professor wants us to prove that every linear mapping from a finite dimensional Banach space is continuous.

BUT, he wants us to do so using the Closed Graph Theorem (in functional analysis). However, I just don't see how to do this... It actually seems way harder to use the Closed Graph Theorem instead of doing [something similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous).  Does anyone have any hints?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T:X\to Y$ is a linear operator with graph $G$, then note that $G$ is a vector subspace of $X\oplus Y$. Using the fact that $X$ is finite dimensional try to convince yourself that $G$ is finite dimensional and hence closed. Now, use the Closed Graph Theorem.