# How to construct unbounded one-to-one linear map?

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $X$ is a normed space, I want to construct an unbounded one-to-one linear map from $X$ to itself, could anyone give some hint?

Comment: Take a normalized Hamel basis of $X$ containing $e_1,e_2,\ldots$. Map $e_n$ to $ne_n$ and the other basis vectors to themselves.

Comment: It is not the same question, but looking at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99206/discontinuous-linear-functional) and some of [other related posts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/99206) might help you.

Comment: @DavidMitra I think that your comment could be posted as an answer.

Comment: You probably want this for *infinite-dimensional* $X$, right? [Every linear mapping on a finite dimensional space is continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin points out in the comments, you can only do this in infinite dimensional spaces. In such a space, there is a normalized (elements of norm $1$) Hamel basis with infinitely many elements (using the Axiom of Choice).

Take such a basis and pick a countably infinite subset $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots\}$ of it.  Map $e_n$ to $ne_n$ and the other basis elements to themselves. Then extend linearly to define a map on the entire space. This gives the desired operator.

Comment: I am thinking what is wrong with your example with finite case. how about choose countably set with norm 1 in finite dimension?

Comment: @89085731 In a finite dimensional space, an infinite set would not be linearly independent; assigning arbitrary values to each element  would likely not give a well-defined linear map.