# Let $U$,$V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional normed vector spaces and let $B:U\times V\rightarrow W$ be a bilinear map. Prove it is differentiable.

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

The derivative at any point $(u,v)\in V\times W$
  is the linear map defined by $(x,y)\longmapsto B(u,y)+B(x,v)$
 . I am trying to prove this using the limit definition. My limit ended up looking like ${{\displaystyle {\lim_{(h_{1},h_{2})\to0}}}}\frac{|B(h_{1},h_{2})|}{|(h_{1},h_{2})|}$
  and I am trying to prove that it is $0$
 , but I don't now how.

Answer (score 1):

For $(u,v) \in U \times V$ you have
$$\begin{aligned}
\Vert B(x+u,y+v)-B(x,y) -(B(u,y)+B(x,v)) \Vert &= \Vert B(u,v) \Vert\\
&\le \Vert B \Vert \Vert u \Vert \Vert v \Vert\\
&\le \frac{\Vert B \Vert}{2} (\Vert u \Vert + \Vert v \Vert)^2
\end{aligned}$$ Hence
$$\lim\limits_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} \frac{\Vert B(x+u,y+v)-B(x,y) -(B(u,y)+B(x,v)) \Vert}{\Vert (u,v) \Vert} = 0$$

as $\Vert u \Vert + \Vert v \Vert$ is a norm on $U \times V$, and on finite dimensional spaces all norms are equivalent.

This proves that $(u,v) \mapsto B(u,y)+B(x,v)$ is the derivative of $B$ at $(x,y)$.

Comment: How can one show that first inequality?

Comment: $x^2+y^2-2xy = (x-y)^2 \ge 0 $

Comment: No I'm talking about the boundlessness property. Does every bilinear map on  finite dimensional spaces have that property?

Comment: For sure $n$-linear maps are continuous on finite dimensional spaces. Proof is similar to the one for linear map.

Comment: It isn't clear to me as well why every bilinear map on a finite dimensional space is bounded.

Comment: @solrak You just need to apply twice what is done for a linear map. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous) for more details.