# Linear function between normed spaces is continous.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $A: X \rightarrow Y$ be linear function between normed spaces $X$, $Y,\  dimX \lt \infty$. Prove that A is continous.

Since $A$ is linear I know that there exists $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $||A(x)||\le k||x||$ for all $x \in X$.

So now I check $||A(x)-A(y)||=||A(x-y)||\le k||x-y||=k\delta=\epsilon$ supposing $||x-y||\lt \delta=\epsilon/k$

Is it a correct proof?

Comment: The same question was posted here:
[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous)

Comment: The proof isn't correct since you're assuming your own thesis. In fact, usually the definition of continuity is given by your second line

Comment: Now I see it. Thanks.

Comment: It looks ok if you properly explain the second line. For example, the norm is continuous, the unit ball in a finite dimensional space is compact plus [Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Generalization_to_metric_and_topological_spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is finite dimensional space, all norms are equivalent in X, so let $(e_i)_i$ be a finite algebriac basis of $X$ and we equipe $X$ by the norme:
$$
\|x:=x_1e_1+\dots x_ne_n\|=\sum_i |x_i|
$$
so 
$$
\|Ax\|=\|\sum_i x_i Ae_i\|\leq\sum_i \|x_i Ae_i\| \leq\max_i \|Ae_i\|\sum_i |x_i|=\alpha \|x\|
$$
Where $\alpha=\max_i \|Ae_i\|<\infty$
So $A$ is continuous