# Dual Space of $R^{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

My teacher said (without explaining why) that because $R^{n}$ is finite dimensional then set of all linear functions (Dual space) is equal to the set of all continuous linear functions. Can someone explaining why this true?

Thank you.

Comment: This can be done by picking a basis in ${\bf R}^{n}$ and examining a particular basis for the dual space and showing that this is indeed a basis.  The particular basis is the *dual basis* {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_basis}

Comment: Every linear map of finite dimensional vector spaces is continous https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112985/every-linear-mapping-on-a-finite-dimensional-space-is-continuous